# Querying the id of an entity using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, querying

In the following method I am trying to fetch the Username by passing the id value where the ids passed as parameter can be multiple values as in csv's (eg: 1,2) and are returned to the calling function as IEnumerable.

Code Follows as below :

```
[NonAction]
public static IEnumerable<UserProfile> SearchCMSAdmins(string s)
{
    //var searchResults = Entities.UserProfiles.Where(item =>item.UserName.Contains(s));
    //return searchResults;

    string[] ids = s.Split(',');

    IEnumerable<UserProfile> results = null;
    IList<UserProfile> user = new List<UserProfile>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(ids[i].ToString());
        var entity = Entities.UserProfiles.Where(item => item.UserId);
        //user.Add(entity);
        results = results.Concat(entity);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should not need ids[i] --> .ToString();, ids are already strings, also, did you mean Entities.UserProfiles.Where(item => item.UserId == i) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Contains`:

```
var results = Entities.UserProfiles.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.UserId));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id` array to be of `int` type, You can either use `int.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32` like:

```
int[] ids = s.Split(',').Select(r=> Convert.ToInt32(r)).ToArray();
```

Later you can modify your LINQ query as:

```
IList<UserProfile> user = Entities.UserProfiles
                                  .Where(item=> ids.Contains(item)).ToList();
```

This would be like `Select * from table where ID in (1,2,3)`  see [Creating IN Queries With Linq to SQL](http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql) for idea

Answer (score 0):

```
[NonAction]
public static IEnumerable<UserProfile> SearchCMSAdmins(string s)
{
    string[] ids = s.Split(',');

    foreach (string idAsString in ids)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(idAsString);
        var entity = Entities.UserProfiles.Where(item => item.UserId == id);
        yield return entity;
    }
}
```

should do it (there should be some validation code too in case the id is not an int or the entity is null)